# Lost Fixed Position on page load jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fixed

Right now I have a script that's similar to this jsFiddle: [Fixed on Scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/jpXjH/6/)

Now if I scroll down it works. But if I refresh the page, the fixed elements disappear until I do a scroll.

I've thought about if the `$(window) > 0` then show it with a if statement. And nothing. Just would like help in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle? It is difficult to debug something without details.

Comment: @Cymen My code is identical to what the sample shows. I don't think you can jsFiddle something that requires a refresh. It just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Given your page is the same as the JSFiddle, I would suggest hooking into the ready event of the page and running the same function that is being run on scroll. So it would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
              $('#navigation').css('position','fixed').css('top','0');
        } else {
            $('#navigation').css('position','static');
        }    
});
```

Comment: Yeah I have a document dot ready setup. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: @nick.hiebert I suggest posting an example that people can interact with. I agree JSFiddle is a bad one due to the refresh. So put it up somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the control-structure into a function and run in onscroll and onready

```
var elementPosition = $('#navigation').offset();

$(window).scroll(shouldStickHeader);
$(document).ready(shouldStickHeader);

function shouldStickHeader () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
          $('#navigation').css('position','fixed').css('top','0');
    } else {
        $('#navigation').css('position','static');
    }
}
```